# VB Script Copy files and progress bar

Tags: vbscript

My code for copying files from source to destination works fine and what i trying to do is only copy files if they are newer ones or with a different names.
Name of the file example abc1.txt and following week this will be replaced with source folder to abc2.txt
Here is the VB Script code.

```
`

Dim intFCount, FSO, strSrcFolder, strDestFolder, strSource, FC, i, intPercentComplete

    i = 0
    intFCount = 0
    intPercentComplete = 0
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strSrcFolder = "\\server\DATA\Production\RUM\"
    strDestFolder = "E:\DATA\Production\test\"

    set strSource = FSO.GetFolder(strSrcFolder)
    set FC = strSource.Files

    for each file in FC
        intFCount = intFCount + 1
    Next

    For Each file in FC
        FSO.CopyFile file, strDestFolder
        i = i + 1
    Next
    2.  I was able to find some progress bar vbs or hta script but struggling to incorporate my copy script to display the progress.  
    Here is the progress bar .hta script found on the net
    <html>
    <head>
    <title id="title">ProgressBar 2.1</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="porgbar" APPLICATIONNAME="progbartest">
    <script language="vbscript">

    Public x,y, MyTitle, iTimerID, KeepGoing

    Sub Window_Onload
    MyTitle = document.Title
    id("ProgBarToDo").innerText = String(80, "_") & "|"  
    window.ResizeTo 720, 200       
    x=0       
    y=35     
    End Sub

    Sub Go
    '---FOR TEST ONLY---
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oof = fso.CreateTextFile("testpb.vbs", True)
    oof.WriteLine "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"  
    oof.Close
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    '----END OF TEST ONLY----

    Progress(1)
    Do Until x=y
    x=x+1
    WshShell.Run "testpb.vbs 250",1,True  '----FOR TEST ONLY
    If KeepGoing = False Or window.screenTop > 10000 Then 
    Exit Do
    End If
    Loop
    Progress(0)
    End Sub

    Sub Progress(v)
    Select Case v
    Case 0  
    window.clearInterval(iTimerID)  
    iTimerID =""             
    id("BtnGo").disabled = False       
    id("BtnCancel").disabled = True    
    id("BtnExit").disabled = False     
    Progress(2)            
    MsgBox "Operation finished.",,MyTitle

    Case 1  
    iTimerID = window.setInterval("Progress(2)", 500)    
    id("BtnGo").disabled = True        
    id("BtnCancel").disabled = False   
    id("BtnExit").disabled = True      
    KeepGoing = True
    Progress(2)         

    Case 2  
    document.Title = FormatPercent(x/y, 0) & MyTitle  
    id("ProgBarText").innerText = x & "/" & y  
    d = Round( x / (y/80)  ,0)   
    id("ProgBarDone").innerText = String(d, "_")  
    If d<80 Then   
    id("ProgBarToDo").innerText = String(80-d, "_") & "|"  
    Else     
    id("ProgBarToDo").innerText = "|"  
    End If

    End Select
    End Sub

    Function id(o)
    Set id = document.getElementById(o)
    End Function

    Sub Help
    MsgBox "This is an example of progressbar in HTA written by Fredledingue.",,MyTitle
    End Sub

    </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="GreenYellow">

    <input id="BtnGo"     type="button" value="Go"     onclick="Go">
    <input id="BtnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="KeepGoing=False" disabled="True">
    <input id="BtnExit"   type="button" value="Exit"   onclick="window.close">
    <input id="BtnHelp"   type="button" value="Help"   onclick="Help">
    <br>

    Done: <span id="ProgBarText">?</span><br>
    <span id="ProgBarDone" style="background-color:blue"></span>
    <span id="ProgBarToDo" style="background-color:silver"></span>

    </body>
    </html>
    `
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Many thanks,
SS

There is also some comparision code found on msdn but i need to check the file abc1.txt exist on server if not copy abc2.txt from server to the local drive.  Here is the code

```
enter code here Option Explicit  
Dim objFSO, wshShell  
Set objFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
On Error Resume Next 
   ProcessScript  
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
      Wscript.Quit  
   End If 
On Error Goto 0  
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
'Name       : ProcessScript -> Primary Function that controls all other script processing.  
'Parameters : None          ->  
'Return     : None          ->  
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Function ProcessScript  
   Dim localFile, serverFile  
   Dim localFileVersion, serverFileVersion  
   localFile  = "C:\rsccc2k\login\login.exe" 
   serverFile = "\\destiny\Install\RSCCC\login.exe" 
   If objFSO.FileExists(localFile) Then 
      If Not GetFileVersion(localFile, localFileVersion) Then 
         Exit Function 
      End If 
      If objFSO.FileExists(serverFile) Then 
         If Not GetFileVersion(serverFile, serverFileVersion) Then 
            Exit Function 
         End If 
      End If 
      If StrComp(localFileVersion, serverFileVersion, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then 
         On Error Resume Next 
            wshShell.Run "\\destiny\Install\RSCCC\RSCCCInstall.bat", 0, true  
         On Error Goto 0  
      End If 
   End If 
End Function 

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
'Name       : GetFileVersion -> Enumerates the version number of a file.  
'Parameters : fileSpec       -> Input  : Folder path and file name for the file to enumerate the version number from.  
'           : fileVersion    -> Output : The file version number of input parameter "fileSpec".  
'Return     : GetFileVersion -> Returns False or True and the version number of the file.  
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Function GetFileVersion(fileSpec, fileVersion)  
   GetFileVersion = False 
   On Error Resume Next 
      fileVersion = objFSO.GetFileVersion(fileSpec)  
      If Len(fileVersion) = 0 Or Err.Number <> 0 Then 
         Exit Function 
      End If 
   On Error Goto 0  
   GetFileVersion = True 
End Function
```

Comment: *"what i trying to do is only copy files if they are newer ones or with a different names"* - Just a suggestion: Maybe it would be easier to just spawn an `xcopy` or `robocopy` process ([via `WSHShell.Run()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx)) instead of trying to implement a file-copying routine from scratch?

Comment: Any help of how i can use xcopy or robocopy process (via WSHShell.Run()) please

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this script with a waiting bar

(script translated by Sree)

```
Option Explicit
Dim sSrc,sDest,MyCmd,Temp,Title,MsgTitle,MsgWaiting,Copyright,oExec,ws,LogTmpFile,LogFile,MyExcludeFile,Settings
Copyright = "[ XcopyScript © Hackoo Crackoo © 2014 ]"
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
sSrc = "C:\Downloads"
sDest = "C:\XCopytest"
LogTmpFile = "MyTmpXCopyLog.txt"
LogFile = "MyXCopyLog.txt"
Settings = " /D /Y /E /F"
MyCmd = "XCopy" & " " & DblQuote(sSrc) & " " & DblQuote(sDest) & " " & Settings &" > " & LogTmpFile &_
" & cmd /U /C Type " & LogTmpFile & " > " & LogFile & " & Del " & LogTmpFile & ""
Title = "Copy backup " & Copyright
MsgWaiting = "Copy backup : <font color=Yellow>" & DblQuote(sSrc) & " to " & DblQuote(sDest) & " </font>  . . . ."
Call CreateProgressBar(Title,MsgWaiting)
Call LaunchProgressBar()
Call Pause(2)
Call Run(MyCmd,0)
Call CloseProgressBar()
ws.run LogFile
'****************************************************************************************************
 Function Run(StrCmd,Console)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'****************************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,MsgWaiting)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID=""ProgressBar""></SPAN>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<span><marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & MsgWaiting &"</font></marquee></span></DIV></CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 500,90"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LaunchProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub CloseProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    WScript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub  
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I have such a routine in vbs only but Tomalak is right, running an external command is going to bu much easier and quicker

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
source = "c:\temp"
target = "c:\temp2"
parameters = "/ds"
oShell.Run "XCOPY " & parameters & " """ & source & """ """ & target & """"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a code for the ***Progress Bar*** that is for 15% maximum but it opens up **Internet Explorer**. If you want to try *this* code then here's the code but you need Internet Explorer 12 (or 11 also probably):

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")
For Each objItem in colItems
    intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
    intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
Next

Set objExplorer = CreateObject _
    ("InternetExplorer.Application")

objExplorer.Navigate "about:blank"   
objExplorer.ToolBar = 0
objExplorer.StatusBar = 0
objExplorer.Left = (intHorizontal - 425) / 2
objExplorer.Top = (intVertical - 100) / 2
objExplorer.Width = 425
objExplorer.Height = 100
objExplorer.Visible = 1             

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 0-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='0' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 1-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='1' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 2-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='2' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 3-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='3' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 4-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='4' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 5-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='5' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 6-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='6' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 7-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='7' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 8-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='8' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 9-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='9' max='15'></progress>"

WScript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 10-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='10' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 11-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='11' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 12-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='12' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 13-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='13' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 14-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='14' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 %"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % -"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 500

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % --"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 500

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 500

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ----"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 500

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- C"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- CO"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COM"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMP"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPL"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLE"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLET"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLETE"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLETE!"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLETE!!"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

Wscript.Sleep 250

objExplorer.Document.Title = "Progress bar = 15-15 % ---- COMPLETE!!!"
objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<progress value='15' max='15'></progress>"

WScript.Quit
```